# Manifest merger failed error: when app building in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, augmented-reality, manifest

When I try to building the Augmented Reality Based android application using unity, I get the following error:
[image: Error]
How to resolve this error?

How to rectify the above issues in unity to get a successful android application using unity

Comment: Change you minimum sdk to 23. In Player Settings

Comment: after i changing the minimum sdk to 23 and i will try to build again, I am getting the following error:  A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade error @Jaimin